# Rounded Corners On Text Input Disappear In Mobile View

Tags: html, css, input, responsive-design, attributes

I'm working on a responsive website project and I decided to round the corners of some div's, buttons and input fields using the border-radius attribute.

Everything looks great except one of the text input's loses half of its rounded corners (on the right side) when I enter into mobile mode.

Can someone give me a clue as to why this might be happening?

Here is some of my code:

```
<!--HTML-->

<section id="newsletter">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Subscribe to our Newsletter</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email...">
            <button type="submit" class="button1">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

```
/* CSS */

#newsletter input[type="email"]{
padding: 4px;
height: 25px;
width: 250px;
border-radius: 12px;
}

.button1{
height: 38px;
background: #e8491d;
border: none;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 12px;
}

.container{
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
#newsletter h1,
#newsletter form{
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#newsletter button{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

#newsletter form input[type="email"]{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
}
```

Thanks!
Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't lose anything - it just overflows. And with overflow: hidden that you have, it's just hidden.

The problem you have is that the input has padding so you need this css rule;

```
* {
       box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

This means that you are including the padding and border in the element's total width and height. (* means all elements). This will fix a lot of weird unexpected behaviour for you in the future. (You should have a look at css resets).

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense and also fixed the problem straight away! My gratitude, sir!